# Error while running python code in Debian11

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, python-idle

I work in Debian 11. Installed pyperclip-1.8.2, run `sudo IDLE` in the console.

Then I type the code below.

I save the file as `1.py`.

When I run the code to monitor the clipboard, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File «/home/debian/Рабочий стол/1.py», line 7, in
    s = pyperclip.paste()
  File «/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyperclip/init.py», line 681, in lazy_load_stub_paste
    return paste()
  File «/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyperclip/init.py», line 301, in paste_klipper
    assert len(clipboardContents) > 0
 AssertionError
```

On the command line, writes «Service ‘org.kde.klipper’ does not exist.».
The code itself:

```
import pyperclip
import time

old = ''
while True:
    s = pyperclip.paste()
    if s != old:
        print(s)
        old = s
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: In the future, format tracebacks as code so they can be read.  Otherwise, the essential linebreaks disappear.  Re-format the code so it matches what was run.  This is almost certainly not an IDLE issue.  You apparently asked pyperclip to paste before you copied or cut anything into the clipboard.  Perhaps you should check before trying to paste?

Comment: I think this is an KDE-related issue from [this ticket](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/issues/202) in the package GitHub repo. It looks like it is still an open issue on their end